# TexStudio does not seem to recognize the updates to the latest versions

Tags: texstudio, update

I hope the title is understandable enough.

So I work with MiKTeX 2.9 and TexStudio editor on a Win 10 Home computer. I just realized that for almost a year now, every time I ran the installer for the new versions of TexStudio, nothing really got installed or at least the installations were not recognized. My current version seems to be 3.0.1 even though the latest release is up to 3.1.2. I realized this was happening when I was signaled the the installer for the newest version was already in my downloads. I ran it and checked if the update actually happened and it had not. I tried running it as an admin as well and it gave the same result. I am not sure what I can do to fix this.

Additionally, a while back I loaded a customized profile since I have problems with my eyes and I needed a dark theme. I don't think this could have caused problems, but please let me know if that's the case and what could be the work around that wouldn't require me to give up this profile since I really need it.

Comment: TeXstudio 3.0.1 is installed in the `Program Files (x86)` folder while TeXstudio 3.1.2 is in the `Program Files`. So first you should uninstall 3.0.1 and then  install 3.1.2 .

Comment: @hair-splitter Thank your for your comment! I was not very eager to do the uninstall and reinstall part since I have made plenty of customizations to the editor over the years but taking your advice I turned it a bit on its head, installing the update in the (x86) folder instead. So far all my files compile correctly and nothing broke so I'll take that as a win. Thank you again!